# PHP Поиск подстроки в ненормальной строке

Tags: php, строки, поиск

Нужно найти название игры в XML файлах от магазинов. Некоторые пишут название так "Metro Exodus", некоторые так: "Metro: Exodus", некоторые так: "Metro: Exodu's".

Надо что бы при поиске строки "metro exodus", находилось и то и другое не зависимо от наличия апострофов двоеточий и т.д.

strpos(); находит только в первом файле игру.

**Подскажите как это сделать?**

Comment: Всего три варианта написания?

Comment: Пока заметил только эти три. Бывает еще когда надо найти число 5, а его написали римским аналогом V, но думаю это уже из области другого вопроса.

Answer (score 3):

С игнорированием символов не получится (наверно?), только регулярка. Если конкретно эта игра, а не любая в принципе...

```
$string = "Metro Exodus"; // Строка, откуда нужно найти подстроку
$res = preg_match("/metro(:?) exodu('?)s/i", $string);
if($res) {
    echo 'Найдено';
} else {
    echo 'Нет соответствий';
}
```

Универсальный вариант:

```
$xml = "Metro: Exodu's";
$need = "metro exodus";

if(strcmp($xml, $need) == 0){
    echo "Всё совпало и так!";
} else {
    $xml = strtolower(preg_replace('/[,.:"!\']/', '', $xml));

    if(strcmp($xml, $need) == 0){
        echo "Всё совпало!";
    } else {
        echo "Что-то пошло не так";
    }
}
```

Comment: лучше сразу `/i`

Comment: @teran, да, лучше так. Поправил.

Comment: Почему спецсимволы не плучится, двоеточие не спец символ?

Comment: Игра не конкретная, а разные. Довольно часто в названиях используется двоеточие

Comment: @РоманРоманюк, добавил более универсальный вариант.

Comment: Спасибо! Я так понял отсекаются запрещенные символы. А можно сделать наоборот - пропускать разрешенные символы? А то вот сейчас нашел название игры "Tom Clancy’s The Division® 2" :|